# Lining up a background image with an icon in CSS

Tags: css

I am trying to line up an icon with a DIV. I have the following code. This code makes the icon appear to the right of the input which is what I want. But it is just too high. I need to shift the icon down.

```
<div>
    <input name="Password" type="password">
    <span style="display: inline-block; margin-top: 9px;" class="ui-icon"></span>
</div>
```

The ui-icon css looks like this:

```
.ui-icon { width: 16px; height: 16px; background-image: url(images/ui-icons_222222_256x240.png); }
```

I tried with margin-top but it doesn't work. What I just need is some way to make the icon go down about 5 pixels. Is there something I am missing?

Comment: Why was the question downgraded?  I just wonder as I thought it was a reasonable question and I had some decent answers. Shame when people like to downgrade just because they can do it without owning up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may do it with CSS like this: (use img instead of background span)

```
vertical-align:middle;
```

or another way could be to set

```
position:relative;
float:left;
top:10px;
```

you may adjust top accordingly.

Comment: This does nothing to change the position of the background-image

Comment: Actually that Does. Please check it here( vertical align):http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_vertical-align

Comment: No, it does not.  You have linked to something that changes the alignment of an `img` tag, and **not** a `background-image` as specified in CSS, which has nothing to do with an `img` tag at all.  Using CSS rather an image also prevents the graphics being a piece of content, which in this case it most likely isn't.

Comment: vertical-align is a neat CSS property which could be applied to spans too. There are multiple ways when it comes to css. Oh and I forgot to add you may use img. my bad.

Comment: Thanks. I am using: container.addClass("ui-icon").addClass("ui-icon-alert").css("position","relative").css("display","inline-block").css("top","3px"); which is inspired by your answer. Someone downgraded you so I upgraded and will mark as correct.

Answer (score 2):

```
background-position:right center;
```

remove `margin-top: 9px;`

Answer (score 1):

You want to use the CSS `background-position` property, you can specify co-ordinates.  See:

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_background-position.asp